Flutter ExpansionTile - Why Android and Web have different Padding?
I have a list with Expansion Tiles in containers, and on the Web it looks ok, but on Android the same code creates much bigger containers. Can you help with that?
Here how it looks:

Here is the code:
body: ListView.builder(
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 6, bottom: 6),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    title: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          thisListName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),


"""but on Android the same code creates much bigger containers.""" most likely because on android the pointer (your finger) is less accurate than the mouse on web platform

@pskink hmm, but can I make it smaller or even have control over it?

On Android, ExpansionTile containers can sometimes appear larger than expected due to platform-specific differences in padding or margins. To create a consistent appearance across platforms, you can explicitly set constraints on the Container and make sure there’s no unexpected padding or margin in the ExpansionTile or child widgets.


PLease donot use screenshot instead copy and paste the entire code for future reference purpose.
